# how to serve multiple laravel project from same server project wise using nginx?

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to serve multiple Laravel projects folder-wise from the same server, such as `ramanath.com/projectA`, `ramanath.com/projectB`, and so on.

The setup below is working only for root routes; however, the routes inside the apps are not working correctly.

Additionally, I want the app names to be dynamic, allowing any project name followed by the server name.

Here's the Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ramanath.com;

    root /var/www/projects;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    location /projectA {
        alias /var/www/projects/projectA/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /projectB {
        alias /var/www/projects/projectB/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /projectC {
        alias /var/www/projects/projectC/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
}
```

With this configuration, only root routes are working for each app. How can I adjust the Nginx configuration to ensure that both root and nested routes within each project work correctly? Also, how can I make the app names dynamic, allowing any valid project name followed by the server name?

Comment: why you don't make it with a subdomain for each website ?!